# Why does ARCore raise fatal error with ARM Graphics Analyser integration?

Tags: android, arm, arcore, mali

I'm trying to use ARM's Graphics Analyzer with an unrooted Samsung SM-A320FL, which has a Mali-T830 GPU.

Just to get things going I'm attempting to analyze a sample app from Google's ARCore SDK with minimal changes. I've taken the "hello_ar_c" sample and added loading of the Graphics Analyzer library (System.loadLibrary("AGA")) to the main activity, added the relevant dir to jniLibs.srcDirs, and installed AGA.apk. abiFilters is set to "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a".

On running the app I get the following error:

```
A/Ion: [vr/gvr/render/platform_surface_manager_android.cc:190] CHECK failed: expression='"context"' Failed to get application context.
```

Not sure how to address this as ARCore and the Graphics Analyzer integration are both closed SDKs.

Thanks a lot for your time.

EDIT:
ARM Graphics Analyzer version tested was 5.3.0.82c6d532.
ARCore SDK version tested was 1.11.0.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report - I'll raise this with the development team.